# Java skips lines of code

Tags: java, jython

I have a JNI wrapper to pass arrays from Fortran to Java. Now, I require Java to pass this array to Python and return the value.

objFuncType.java is as follows:

```
public interface objFuncType {
    public double calculateobjFunc(double[] pos);
}
```

objFunc.java is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.plyjy.factory.JythonObjectFactory;

public class objFunc {

public static double evaluate(double[] position) {
    double result;
    for (int i=0;i<position.length;i++)
       System.out.println("position ="+position[i]);

    JythonObjectFactory factory = JythonObjectFactory.getInstance();
    System.out.println("JythonObjectFactory created");
    objFuncType func=(objFuncType)factory.createObject(objFuncType.class, "CostCalculator");
    result = func.calculateCost(position);
    System.out.println("Result computed! Result = "+result);
    return result;

    }
}
```

CostCalculator.py is as follows:

```
import objFuncType

class CostCalculator(objFuncType, object):

def __init__(self):
    print 'Initializing'
    pass

def calculateCost(self, chromosome):
    fitness = 0
    for i in range(len(chromosome)-1):
        fitness += 100*((chromosome[i]**2)-chromosome[i+1])**2+\
        (1-chromosome[i])**2
    return fitness
```

When I call the Java function from an external program, the output is as follows:

```
position =1.3653333187103271
position =0.0
position =-1.8204443454742432
position =-1.8204443454742432
```

The array is being printed fine but all the statements after the print statement are skipped. 
Please help!

Comment: How do you know they are being "skipped"? Are you sure there isn't a runtime error in there somewhere?

Comment: try checking for exception by `try catch`

Comment: When I exclude the JNI part and move the code from the method 'evaluate' to the main method, it works fine. However, when I integrate this code with my existing JNI wrapper, only the first print statement outputs the array. The rest of the statements are ignored and I don't see the output for the rest of the print statements. I don't get any runtime errors.

Comment: Comment out the factory declaration; should get the next println.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yes, that works. But, I want the JythonObjectFactoryDeclaration there though. I don't understand why it's not being instantiated.

Comment: @singhakash: I did. No exceptions caught.

Comment: `catch (Throwable ex)` - to be sure?

Comment: @JoopEggen: Thanks a ton! The output includes this statement - "Exception caught: org/plyjy/factory/JythonObjectFactory"
Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Not using jython last time. However this can be prototyped separately, searching code in the web. Success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I was invoking Java from C using JNI and it looks like it didn't know where to look for the jar files. I added the following lines of code in my C program that invokes Java. It runs as expected.

```
JNIEnv* env;
JavaVMInitArgs args;
JavaVMOption options[3];
args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
args.nOptions = 3;
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_class>:<path_to_jars>";
options[2].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=<path_to_class>:<path_to_jars>";
args.options = options;
args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
int status;
status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
if (status < 0 || !env)
    printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n",rv);
else
    printf("Launched JVM successfully\n");
return env;
```